# Looking for a alert on multi time frame

Tags: pine-script

alert when RSI14 is crosing 60 on 30min chart, if RSI14 is above 60 on 1hr chart & if RSI14 is above 60 on 1day chart,

basically to find a confirm bullish trend, please help me to achive this.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go my dude, try to figure out on your own next time but thought I'd help you out. Pretty simple actually, I also made it so you can adjust the lengths of each RSI individually. Read through it so you can understand how it works. I'm a beginner myself but this should work as intended.

```
//@version=4
study("MTF RSI", overlay=false)

//custom input for rsi lengths and timeframes
rsilen=input(14, minval=1, title="1st RSI Length", type=input.integer)
rsilen2=input(14, minval=1, title="2nd RSI Length", type=input.integer)
rsilen3=input(14, minval=1, title="3rd RSI Length", type=input.integer)
rsires=input("30", title="1st RSI Timeframe", type=input.resolution)
rsires2=input("60", title="2nd RSI Timeframe", type=input.resolution)
rsires3=input("1D", title="3rd RSI Timeframe", type=input.resolution)

//variables for each rsi
RSI1=rsi(close, rsilen)
RSI2=rsi(close, rsilen2)
RSI3=rsi(close, rsilen3)

//different timeframes for rsi
rsi1=security(syminfo.tickerid, rsires, RSI1)
rsi2=security(syminfo.tickerid, rsires2, RSI2)
rsi3=security(syminfo.tickerid, rsires3, RSI3)

//plots all 3 RSIs
plot(rsi1, title="1st RSI", color=color.red)
plot(rsi2, title="2nd RSI", color=color.green)
plot(rsi3, title="3rd RSI", color=color.blue)

//alert condition
alertcondition(rsi1 > 60 and rsi2 > 60 and rsi3 > 60, title="3 RSI Bullish", message="All 3 RSIs Bullish")
```